# use >nul when execute command by runtime.exec

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am executing a self-defined command like following code.I know that append a `>nul` to command will prevent from outputing error or other message to console.But in my code,`>nul` is treated as a parameter of my own command `deletefile`.So the command can not execute as expected.How to resolve it?

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process p = runtime.exec("deletefile /name:\"ABC\" /owner:\"Wolfman\" >nul");
    int status = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(status);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Solution is:
`cmd deletefile /name:\"ABC\" /owner:\"Wolfman\" >nul`

Comment: The code is not a batch file or MSDos.

Comment: If this was MSDos, you would be able to put a ^ in front of the > character so that it would treat it like a character and not interpret it as a redirection command, like this `\"Wolfman\" ^nul"`.  But like @foxidrive said, this isn't MSDos.  Did you try `\"Wolfman\" \>nul"`?

Comment: Have you tried starting your program from `cmd`? `runtime.exec("cmd /c deletefile /name:\"ABC\" /owner:\"Wolfman\" >nul")`?

Comment: Yes,it is not MSDos.I have updated the tag of my question.I just try `cmd deletefile /name:\"ABC\" /owner:\"Wolfman\" >nul`,command work well.